# Strange random numbers at the end of .js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I have a strange problem, and I don't know where to start to search. My file /nat.js in chrome developer tools shows /nat.js:35, /nat.js:5, /nat.js:16 or /nat.js:6 and all that paths are inaccessible. Only when I directly type http:xxxxx/test/nat.js is reachable, but on-page is not. Does someone know why js files adding that random numbers? What causing those redirections to not accessible pages?

Thanks.

Comment: They are the line numbers where your issue exists.

Comment: ok, I have a starting point now :-) I will investigate. Thank you.

Comment: And usually when you click on that file, it opens it and scrolls to the need line.